# Ios Parse framework and Facebook clientKey

Tags: ios, social-networking, parse-platform, fbconnect

I'm trying to integrate FB in my app using the Parse (www.parse.com). In AppDelegate I must set  the ParseCredentials :

> [Parse setApplicationId:@"your_application_id"
>   clientKey:@"your_client_key"];

your_application_id = my FB AppId
  your_client_key = ???

I don't know how to set this parameter.
  I tried to fill with the AppSecretId but doesn't work.

I receive this error : "`Error: Error Domain=com.parse.networking.error Code=-1011` "

Can someone help me with some advice about this problem? Thank you!

Comment: have you created app on facebook ?

Comment: Yes I have the AppID and the secretAppID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must register on parse.com and create new app.

In the settings tab of the app you will see the ApplicationId and ClientKey.

[image]